# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with two different src folders

Tags: java, junit

I have 2 source folders in the same project, one called `layout` and other one called `user`. There is a class called `genLayout` in the `layout` source folder which generates a layout class (extends from a given class) for the class in the `user` source folder. Here is some of the code:

```
    GenLayout loader = new GenLayout(interfaceClass);
    byte[] bytes = loader.dump();
    implClass = defineClass(null, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

the problem is once I run the jUnit test case, it throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.user.types.Byte
```

`com.user.types.Byte` is a self-defined class, and has nothing to do with primitive type byte

The test case works fine if I put all files in the same src folder.

Two source folders have different output folders, one called `layout_bin` and other one is `user_bin`

here is the .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="layout_bin" path="layout"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="user_bin" path="user"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/VM_Test/VM/lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/VM_Test/VM/lib/asm-all-4.0.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: How are you compiling this? What is on your classpath?

Comment: You haven't shown where you're using `com.user.types.Byte`, but you are using `byte[]`. Have you confused these?

Comment: oh sorry for the confusion. In this case, interfaceClass is com.user.types.Byte

Comment: set your `classpath` correctly, that should help you.